# Apache Storm multilang broken issue

Tags: java, python, apache-storm

we are running storm topology in Java. There is a bolt that uses Python scripts. For that, we are using Multilang (ShellBolt). When the rebalance happens in the topology we are seeing below error,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read. Serializer Exception: at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShe
```

This is the code that calls the Python model

```
public pythoncallBolt(String pythonpath, String pythonfilepath) {
        super(pythonpath,pythonfilepath);

    }
```

Please, anyone, help us to fix this issue

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you expect to happen instead? When you rebalance the topology, Storm will kill some of the workers if the tasks need to be moved to a different worker. I don't know for sure, but the error log you're seeing might be getting logged because the Python process is shutting down?